# Bigquery not in like equivalent

Tags: google-bigquery

Looking a way to do a "not in like" with bigquery. I tried

```
SELECT
  e.*
FROM
  T1 AS e
JOIN EACH T2 AS a
ON
  e.filename NOT LIKE CONCAT(a.filename, "%");
```

or

```
SELECT
  e.*
FROM
  T1 AS e
JOIN T2 AS a
ON
  REGEXP_MATCH(e.filename, CONCAT(a.filename, ".*" ))
```

Give the same error

```
ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name. .
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your ON clause violate below requirement:

```
ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name. .
```

you can use

```
SELECT e.* FROM T1 AS e
CROSS JOIN  T2 AS a
WHERE <condition>
```

instead of

```
SELECT e.* FROM T1 AS e
JOIN  T2 AS a ON <condition>
```

Comment: But be careful: CROSS JOIN is expensive! Filter both sides of the join as much as possible prior to the join. And wherever possible, put *something* in the ON clause to help BQ partition your data, even if you need to do further filtering post-join.

Comment: That's right. Should of mentioned this in my answer. Filtering as much as possible as early as possible will reduce your billingTier. Using ONLY fields/columns you need (at least in most outter select) - will reduce your totalBytesBilled. As you know your billingCost= totalBytesBilled x billingTier. See more details at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute

Comment: SELECT
  e.filename, a.file_
FROM
  T1 AS e
CROSS JOIN T2 AS a
where
a.file_ not like CONCAT(e.filename, "%")
LIMIT 10 give me result but dont know if this the good one. :(